# How to put Italics and Plain text in bquote of xlab and ylab?

Tags: r

I would need my R plot to show  something like this  *"S. aureus Area (mm2)"* in the x and y labels. *"E.coli"* should be in Italics and "2" should be a superscript.
I am working with `ggplot2` and my R code is:

```
ylab(bquote(italic ('S. aureus'),plain ('Area ('*mm^2*')')))+
xlab(bquote(italic('E. coli'),plain('Area ('*mm^2*')')))
```

The resultant graph shows "S.aureus" and "E.coli" correctly in italics on the y and x axes, but it doesn't report the rest of the title. So, the second part of the xlab and xlab code needs to be changed..Could you help me, please?
Thank you very much in advance.
Silvia

Comment: does `expression( paste(italic("S. aureus")," Area ('mm^2')"))` help?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
labs(x=expression(italic(S.aureus)~Area~(mm^2)),y=expression(italic(E.coli)~Area~(mm^2)))
```